# How can I use decltype on a variable in a lambda without capturing it?

Tags: c++, lambda, decltype

I'm trying to design a C++ macro that needs to look something like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO(OBJECT, METHOD)                            \
    [](BaseClass* obj)                                      \
    {                                                       \
        return static_cast<decltype(OBJECT)>(obj)->METHOD();\
    }
```

Basically, a macro that translates into a lambda that calls a given method on a given object.  But the lambda needs to take a base class of the object as a parameter (My use case guarantees that the cast will always work).  Furthermore, the method to be called might not be on the base class.

The usage for this macro is that I have another method which I cannot modify declared as:

```
void Foo(std::function<int(BaseClass*)>);
```

and I need to be able to call it using my macro as a parameter like so:

```
T x;
Foo(MY_MACRO(x, method));  // match std::function<int(T*)>
```

However, the macro code doesn't work because I'm not capturing OBJECT, so it's not in scope when I need to pass it to decltype.  Conceptually though, all the information the compiler needs is there... How can I do this?  Is it possible?

A few constraints:

1. The lambda's parameter needs to be BaseClass.  I can't make it decltype(OBJECT).
2. My situation does not allow me to capture OBJECT.
3. I don't have access to the C++14 feature of generalized lambda captures.

Comment: Have you considered `std::mem_fn`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but I can't use it in my situation.  I'm generalizing my problem statement; in truth, it's not quite this simple.  But the bottom line is that it needs to be a lambda and I need access to the type of the object without capturing it.

Comment: Can you add a usage example, just for illustration?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: The usage example in question would be what is actually getting passed to the macro.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I embellished the example a bit.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but why not just pass the desired typename as a parameter value to the macro directly, instead of trying to make the lambda figure it out? `#define MY_MACRO(OBJECTTYPE, METHOD) [](BaseClass* obj) { return static_cast<OBJECTTYPE>(obj)->METHOD(); } ... Foo(MY_MACRO(T, method));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an optional parameter to the lambda with the type that you want, and use `decltype` on that parameter. Here's an example of the pattern, minus the macro:

```
int main() {
    int foo = 4;
    auto lambda = [](double* bar, decltype(foo)* TP = nullptr) {
        return static_cast<std::remove_pointer<decltype(TP)>::type>(*bar);
    };

    double x = 5;
    return lambda(&x);
}
```

I get a pointer to `decltype(foo)` here because pointer types can easily be defaulted to `nullptr` to ensure that the parameter is optional. If `decltype(foo)` already resolves to a pointer type, as in your case if I got it right, you wouldn't need it (and the `remove_pointer`).

Comment: I can't do this, sadly, because I need the macro to evaluate to something that matches std::function<int(BaseClass*)>.  Don't worry about the int, my use case guarantees the types will always match up.

Comment: @PaulAccisano, you might be able to get away by capturing that lambda in another lambda that has the correct signature.

Comment: @PaulAccisano, no, wait, you don't even need that. The lambda can go straight in a `std::function` of that type: http://cppshell.com/2uy5x

Comment: Whoa!  I didn't know std::function was that flexible!  Awesome!  I think this is the way to go then.

Comment: Works like a dream!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> I need access to the type of the object without capturing it.

You can do it directly. You are required to capture only when you odr-use the named entity, and unevaluated operands, like those of `decltype`, don't odr-use anything. This is perfectly fine:

```
void f(){
    int x; 
    []{ decltype(x) y = 0; };
}
```

Comment: Interesting, this fails to compile in Visual Studio.  Compiler bug?

Comment: @PaulAccisano MSVC, huh? /sigh

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt:

```
template <typename T>
auto lambda_maker(int (T::* MF)())
{
    return [](T* p) -> int { return (p->*MF)(); };
}

#define MY_MACRO(OBJ, METH) lambda_maker<decltype(OBJ)>(METH)
```