# How to use the pthreads library in C++ with functional lambdas?

Tags: c++, casting, pthreads

I want to use the pthreads library in C++ with C++ lambdas. My lambdas are of the type `std::function<void(X)>` when X can be any type such as `int`, `double`, `float` or a custom type. Moreover, it is possible that the lambda accepts more than one parameter. For example, I can have a lambda of the type `std::function<void(float,int)>`. Now I want to cast this lambda to a C style function pointer which takes in a single `void*` arguments and returns a `void*` type. So I want to cast my lambda to a function pointer of the type `void* (*)(void*)`.

I want to do this so that I can pass this function pointer to the pthread_create API. Can someone please tell me how can I do this?

I think that since the target type accepts a `void*` argument, I'll need to create a wrapper function of the type `void* my_wrapper(void*)` which would call the lambda inside its body. Then I think I should be able to pass a pointer to the wrapper to the pthreads API.

Moreover, I will also need a way to capture the lambda arguments so that I can wrap them up in a custom structure whose pointer I can then pass to the wrapper.

Comment: I suggest that you use standard C++ `std::thread`s instead of the platform specific C library pthreads

Comment: I am asking a very specific question which is how to cast a std::function to void*(*)(X). I don't know how much more specific you want me to be.

Comment: A lambda will not be a std::function<void(float,int)> it will have its own type. It might be convertible to such a function type though. I usually use std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ function(float1,int1); }; to launch things in background threads. Don't use pthreads, with C++ you will have std::mutex/std::scoped_lock to be able to handle your locks in an RAII (exception safe) way too.  Which greatly reduces the risks for deadlocks when you have bugs.

Comment: @Setu You cannot, a std;:function is not a function pointer. You can cast a lambda to a function pointer but only if it has no captures.  From C++ weekly : [casting lambdas to function pointers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cmk0Tlo1eCA)

Comment: So is there no way to cast a std::function pointer? If no, is there a way to wrap it in a lambda and then cast the lambda to a function pointer?

Comment: That API has that void* argument for storing whatever context (can be pointer to lambda but you have to take care of its life-time by other means); function should be real function and so can not store context in itself.

Comment: Use `std::thread` like suggested above by @TedLyngmo and you won't need to cast into a function pointer.

Comment: @Setu Based on your comment you should [edit] your question so pthread is not a leading theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating a lambda, callable without parameters and returning `void *`. Presumably it'd call your `std::function` with an appropriate parameter.

```
auto lambda = [&]() -> void *
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return nullptr;
};
```

Then create another lambda:

```
auto caller = [](void *data) -> void *
{
    return (*static_cast<decltype(lambda) *>(data))();
};
```

`caller(&lambda)` calls `lambda()`.

Now you can pass `caller` to `pthread_create`, with `&lambda` as the argument.

Comment: Small nitpick - I would make `lambda` return `void` instead of `void*`, and move `return nullptr` into `caller` since it is the actual pthread callback. `lambda` shouldn't care that pthread even exists, let alone that it wants a `void*` return value.

Comment: In any case, does this even compile? Wouldn't `caller` have to capture `lambda` in order to use `decltype(lambda)`? If so, then this wont work since a capturing lambda can't be used with pthreads. Even if it did work, the lifetime of `lambda` is an issue, as it needs to stay alive the whole time the pthread is running.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It does compile, I think because the special case of `decltype`ing a variable doesn't care about captures.

Comment: I know (now) that it compiles (I tried it), I was just wondering why it compiles. Apparently, that has already been asked and answered: [How can I use decltype on a variable in a lambda without capturing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479655/)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. However, I don't fully understand how the typecasting is working here. Can you please post some source which could explain this. Thanks!

Comment: @Setu There is not much to explain here. A lambda is a class (member variables are the captures) and an overloaded `operator()`. We pass a pointer to this class, cast it to the correct type, then call with `()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I assume by casting it to correct type you mean the `*static_cast<decltype(lambda) *>` statement. However `decltype(lambda)` would be `void*` since the return type of the lambda is `void*`. That means that the cast statement reduces to `*static_cast<void**>`. Since data itself is of the type `void*`, the code would end up effectively doing `return (*(void**)data)();`. What I don't understand is why did you cast data into `void**` since you anyways end up de-referencing it. So `return data();`  should have been equivalent, if I have understood this code snippet correctly.

Comment: @Setu *"However `decltype(lambda)` would be `void*` since the return type of the lambda is `void*`."*, No, that would be `decltype(lambda())`. `decltype(lambda)` gives you a type that otherwise has no name; the class type created by the lambda.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah I see. Thanks. I had overlooked the lack of `()`. Also, but then the `caller` and the  `lambda` are equivalent. Then I should be able to pass `lambda` directly if I remove the capture by reference bit. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Setu If you remove `[&]`, how are you going to access the `std::function` that needs to be called and the arguments to pass to it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see. Would a capture by value work? Or do I need to have a capture by reference?

Comment: @Setu Any capture is fine.